# Add 2 dataframes with no exact index values

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have this df:

```
df1
          t0
ACER      50
BBV       20
ACC       75
IRAL      25
DECO      58
```

and on the other side :

```
df2
          t1
ACER      50
BBV       20
CEL        0
DIA       25
```

I am looking forward to add both dfs to obtain the following output:

```
df3
          t2
ACER      100
BBV       40
ACC       75
IRAL      25
DECO      58
DIA       25 
CEL        0
```

Basically is the addition of the common index values in `df1` and `df2` and include those that didnt appeared in `df1`

I tried a

```
d1.add(df2)
```

but Nan values arised, I also thought in merging dfs, substitute Nans by zeros and add columns , but I think maybe is lot of code to perform this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use concat and sum

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).sum(1)

ACC      75.0
ACER    100.0
BBV      40.0
CEL       0.0
DECO     58.0
DIA      25.0
IRAL     25.0
```

Comment: Much better your method. Thank you

Comment: Nice alternative!

Comment: Alternative :`pd.concat([df1, df2.rename(columns={'t1':'t0'})], axis=0).sum(level=0)`

Answer (score 1):

You were actually on the right track, you just needed `fill_value=0`:

```
df1.t0.add(df2.t1, fill_value=0).to_frame('t2')

         t2
ACC    75.0
ACER  100.0
BBV    40.0
CEL     0.0
DECO   58.0
DIA    25.0
IRAL   25.0
```

Note here that you'd have to add the `Series` objects together to prevent misalignment issues.